# Can somebody show me step by step how to simplify$ \frac{ae^{ax}}{1+e^{ax}} -\frac{ae^{2ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^{2}}$ to $\frac{ae^{ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$
f(x) = \frac{ae^{ax}}{1+e^{ax}}  -\frac{ae^{2ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^{2}}
$$

$f(x)$ simplified to  $\frac{ae^{ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^{2}}$

I am getting $\frac{ae^{ax} -a e^{2ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^{2}}$

Comment: Please write your formulas using mathjax. It will help us to read them correctly.

Comment: I don't know what that is. I've trying to figure this out for hours

Comment: It's okay it's edited now, but you might want to learn Latex the next time so your question becomes clear.

Comment: Now you got someone else doing that for you. If you edit your question you will see what it looks like. Now, please show us how you got arrived at the expression you arrived at.

Comment: Cross multiplied and subtracted/divided out like terms

Comment: I feel as though the only way to get the simplified answer is to do extensive multiplication, then factoring to eliminate terms. You can't do it with just  the factored terms you get from cross multiplying

Comment: $\frac{ae^{ax}}{1+e^{ax}}  -\frac{ae^{2ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^{2}} = \frac{ae^{ax}(1+e^{ax})}{(1+e^{ax})^2}  -\frac{ae^{2ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^{2}}$ ... expand the numerator of the first fraction & observe that the second terms cancels ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = \frac{ae^{ax}}{1+e^{ax}} - \frac{ae^{2ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^2} = \frac{ae^{ax}(1+e^{ax}) - ae^{2ax}}{(a+e^{ax})^2} = \frac{ae^{ax} + ae^{2ax} - ae^{2ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^2} = \frac{ae^{ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^2}$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{ae^{ax}}{1+e^{ax}}  -\frac{ae^{2ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^{2}} = 
\frac{ae^{ax}(1+e^{ax})}{(1+e^{ax})(1+e^{ax})}-\frac{ae^{2ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^{2}} = 
 \frac{ae^{ax}(1+e^{ax})-ae^{2ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^2}=
\frac{ae^{ax}+ae^{2ax}-ae^{2ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^2}= 
\frac{ae^{ax}}{(1+e^{ax})^2}
$